# How do I query a single variable of an object in Room database?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-room

I have successfully retrieved and displayed all the `Room` data using:

```
@Query( "SELECT * FROM my_table" )
LiveData<List<MyRoomEntity>>getAllData();
```

but I struggle when querying for a single variable. I have tried this:

```
@Query( "SELECT name FROM my_table" )
LiveData<List<MyRoomEntity>>getAllNames();
```

but it gives me the following `error message`:

`Error:(31, 33) error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [id] in xxx even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [name]`

Does this mean that I *have to* include the `id` as well because it's non-nullable (primitive)?

How do I get around it? Can I make it into an `Integer` so that it can be nullable? If so, are automatically nulled (not included) in my query?

I have tried adding my `variable` (name) as a `String` to the list instead, like this:

```
@Query( "SELECT name FROM my_table" )
LiveData<List<String>>getAllNames();
```

And while it works, it's not a solution since the `List` is to be passed to a `RecyclerView` which accepts an `MyRoomEntity` object.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Last query is fine since "name" is type `String` and not `MyRoomEntity`. Use first query with * to grab type `MyRoomEntity`

Comment: Yes, but I need the `name` query to be of type `MyRoomEntity` so that it can be passed to my `RecyclerView`. The `RecyclerView` doesn't take a `String`.

Comment: with name you return a `String` type so you cannot cast `String` to `yourObject`. The return type should be the same as `yourObject`(type). Check instead of name to put every fields there (as * : same things).

Comment: Sorry, I might be a bit daft. Could you please elaborate? @Traian :)

Comment: First and Last query worked because types were match (`*` for `MyRoom`, `name` for `String`). But `name` is not type `MyRoom` is `String` and that way cannot be cast to `MyRoom` so error raise on Second query. if instead of `*` , made another query with all fields from table (same return order of `*`) this should work also. eg: `Select name, id, other_field, etc from` because `(name,id,other_field,..)` is type `MyRoom`. Hope to be more clear now. Other similarity: `String s; Integer i;`but cannot write `i=(Integer) s` (wrong cast) –

Comment: That did make a lot of sense - it worked! :) Thanks alot @Traian :)

Comment: Glad to be helpful